# How to dynamically pass variables from HTML to CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem. I don't know how (and if it is possible) to pass some variable from HTML to CSS.
For example, I've got a CSS code:

```
.clear {
clear: both;
display: block;
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;
width:100%;
}
```

And I want to pass variable to width instead of writting 100%.

Comment: Neither HTML nor CSS have any concept of "variables". So: no.

Comment: Though depending on what you are actually attempting to accomplish, you might be interested in calc(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use javascript:

```
var myVar = "100%";
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('clear');
for (var i in elements) {
    elements[i].style.width = myVar;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) And in CSS i sipmly delete line with width:100%?

Comment: yes, unless you want a default before running the js code.